# Ruby on Rails migration stuck

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, database-migration

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and would be grateful for some help with migrations.
Version 4

first migration

```
class CreateRooms < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :rooms do |t|
      t.integer :legacy_id, null: true
      t.string :tag, null: false
      t.string :name_en, null: false
      t.string :name_et, null: false
      t.string :name_ru, null: false
      t.string :color, default: 'Black'
      t.timestamp :enabled_from, default: 0
      t.timestamp :enabled_to, default: 0
      t.timestamps null: false 
    end
    add_index :rooms, :tag, unique: true
    add_index :rooms, :name_en, unique: true
    add_index :rooms, :name_et, unique: true
    add_index :rooms, :name_ru, unique: true

  end
end
```

next one

```
class AddDefaultValuesToRoom < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :rooms, :priority, :integer, null: false
    change_column :rooms, :enabled_from, :datetime, default: '2008-08-15'
    change_column :rooms, :enabled_to, :datetime, default: '2050-12-31'
    add_index :rooms, :priority, unique: true
  end
end
```

Strangely enough this is not reflected in schema

```
  create_table "rooms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "legacy_id"
    t.string   "tag",                                          null: false
    t.string   "name_en",                                      null: false
    t.string   "name_et",                                      null: false
    t.string   "name_ru",                                      null: false
    t.string   "color",        default: "Black"
    t.datetime "enabled_from", default: '2008-08-15 00:00:00'
    t.datetime "enabled_to",   default: '2050-12-31 00:00:00'
    t.datetime "created_at",                                   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                   null: false
  end

  add_index "rooms", ["name_en"], name: "index_rooms_on_name_en", unique: true
  add_index "rooms", ["name_et"], name: "index_rooms_on_name_et", unique: true
  add_index "rooms", ["name_ru"], name: "index_rooms_on_name_ru", unique: true
  add_index "rooms", ["tag"], name: "index_rooms_on_tag", unique: true
```

rake db:rollback crashes

```
 rake db:rollback STEP=2 --trace
** Invoke db:rollback (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:rollback
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Migrating to AddDefaultValuesToRoom (20160127121254)
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
== 20160127121254 AddDefaultValuesToRoom: reverting ===========================
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration/command_recorder.rb:65:in `inverse_of'
```

Now I'm in a fix, could somebody help me out ?

TIA
Pavel

Answer (score 0):

`change_column` creates an irreversible change to your database, which means you can't roll it back. See the guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-columns

The idea here is that reverting your data would result in data loss, so Rails prevents you from doing something destructive by default and throws an error to stop the process.

Change your last migration to utilize `reversible` or `up`/`down` methods, in order to explicitly tell Rails how to reverse your change (note that you will lose any data stored in the new column `priority`). See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-reversible

Here's an example using `up`/`down` methods:

```
class AddDefaultValuesToRoom < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :rooms, :priority, :integer, null: false
    change_column :rooms, :enabled_from, :datetime, default: '2008-08-15'
    change_column :rooms, :enabled_to, :datetime, default: '2050-12-31'
    add_index :rooms, :priority, unique: true
  end

  def down
    remove_column :rooms, :priority
    change_column :rooms, :enabled_from, :datetime, default: 0
    change_column :rooms, :enabled_to, :datetime, default: 0
  end
end
```